# GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationHandler + SSL Termination - redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, oauth

I have an application hidden after HAProxy.

There is SSL termination. 
My application is https://myapp.domain.com but in HttpContext.Request applications recognize it as http://myapp.domain.com (no SSL because it is terminated at proxy level).

The problem is that I use Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google library. 
When it generates a redirect_uri with http instead of https.

I have checked the implementation of GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationHandler => ApplyResponseChallengeAsync() method and it clearly shows that this redirect_uri is generated from server side data:

```
    string str1 = this.Request.Scheme + Uri.SchemeDelimiter + (object) this.Request.Host + (object) this.Request.PathBase;
    string str2 = str1 + (object) this.Request.Path + (object) this.Request.QueryString;
    string str3 = str1 + (object) this.Options.CallbackPath;
```

The question is how I can force this provider to get a valid url scheme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem. 
The **Request.Scheme** in this context is not **HttpRequest** but **IOwinRequest**.

It can be overriden globally in Startup.cs file:

```
    app.Use((context, next) =>
    {
        context.Request.Scheme = context.Request.GetRealScheme(true);
        return next();
    });
```

where **GetRealScheme()** is my extension method:

```
    private const string HeaderProtoKey = "X-Forwarded-Proto";

    public static string GetRealScheme(this IOwinRequest request, bool skipPostfix = false)
    {
        if (request == null)
            return null;

        string headerProtocol = request.Headers[HeaderProtoKey] ?? string.Empty;

        string result = headerProtocol.ToLower().Contains("https")
            ? "https://"
            : request.Scheme;

        return skipPostfix
            ? result.Replace("://", string.Empty)
            : result;
    }
```

One important thing to note!

This code should be applied **BEFORE** authentication setup.